# CSS animation in different browsers

Tags: html, css, animation

Working in Google chrome the animation code I have below works fine.

In Firefox and IE it doesnt work at all.

The idea is to have two background images one with a missing spot and the other image is just the spot.

With the animation taking place the missing spot fades in and out on the animation loop.

Like I said, it works perfect in google chrome. How do I get this to work with Firefox and IE?

```
        @keyframes web_butanim
        {
            from {
            background-image: url(./web_button1.png);
          }

          to {
            background-image: url(./web_button2.png);
          }

        }

        #Websites_but
        {
            background-image: url(./web_button1.png);
            background-size:cover;
            animation-duration:0.8s;
            animation-name:web_butanim;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;                
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this it makes sense https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: You are not using -moz and -webkit prefix in keyframes